# How to create a custom made function instance of Eq and Ord

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass, haskell-platform, rational-number

I've implemented a normalisation function **normaliseRat :: Rat -> Rat** for rational numbers so that all of Rat 2 4, Rat (-1) (-2) and Rat 1 2 are transformed into the same internal representation. Furthermore, implemented a function createRat :: Integer -> Integer -> Rat that, given two Integers, returns a normalised Rat.
Note: I used the Prelude that contains a function gcd to compute the greatest common divisor of two integers.

```
gcd' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
gcd' a b = if b == 0 then a else gcd' b (a `mod` b)

data Rat = Rat Integer Integer

normaliseRat :: Rat -> Rat
normaliseRat (Rat num den) =
    let commonDivisor = gcd' (abs num) (abs den)
        num' = num `div` commonDivisor
        den' = den `div` commonDivisor
    in Rat (if den < 0 then (-num') else num') (abs den')

createRat :: Integer -> Integer -> Rat
createRat num den = normaliseRat (Rat num den)

-- Adding the Show instance for Rat
instance Show Rat where
    show (Rat num den) = show num ++ "/" ++ show den
```

This program is giving the expected result. Like:

```
ghci>createRat 2 4
ghci> rat1
1/2
```

Now I want to make **Rat** an instance of **Eq and Ord**. Of course, **Rat 2 4 == Rat 1 2** should evaluate to True.

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: Actually, I'm new to Haskell. So I didn't know how can I implement this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to ensure that `Rat 2 4` is not a value that can be constructed. Do this by only exposing the part of the API that preserves normalization. For example:

```
module Rat (
    Rat, -- expose the type, but not the data constructor
         -- (compare an export of Rat(Rat) or Rat(..) which would export both)
    createRat,
    )

-- because rationals are always created already-reduced, the
-- derived Eq instance is good enough
data Rat = Rat Integer Integer deriving Eq

createRat :: Integer -> Integer -> Rat
createRat = undefined

-- reduction isn't enough if you want the usual ordering on
-- rationals, so we need to implement this one ourselves
instance Ord Rat where compare (Rat n d) (Rat n' d') = undefined
```

This is a fairly standard technique, and you can find more resources using "smart constructor" as a search term.

As an aside, I would recommend deriving your `Show` instance. If you'd like a way to show rationals that is prettier, export a function specifically for that, named `showRat` or similar. This, too, is a common practice.

Answer (score 0):

We know that two fractions *a/b* and *c/d* are equal if *a×d = c×b* (given the denominators are not zero), so we can implement the `Eq` instance as:

```
instance Eq Rat where
    Rat a b == Rat c d = a * d == b * c
```

I leave the instance of `Ord` as an exercise. This will be more complicated, since the denominators can be negative as well.